# Multiple WebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have four buttons that have a link to it. How can I have the webview go to that certain link when the button is clicked and so on with the other buttons? I thought it will be like this but it wasn't

```
WebView.detailURL = [[[redLinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@\"URL\"];
```

Comment: What happens? Does the code compile? Does it run but crash? If it doesn't crash, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Reload your webView with new detailURL

```
[yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:detailURL]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but from what i understood you need something like this

```
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
```

where you put something like that in an IBAction for each of the buttons and change "google.com" to what you need it to be